# Firebase database not working after uploading application to play store

Tags: firebase, google-play, google-developers-console

I have updated SHA-1 key to firebase project settings from Google Play console. Also I have added release and debug SHA-1 keys. But still google team can't able to use the app. It is login successfully with testing mobile number and OTP, but after that it will fetch data from firebase database in an activity. At that moment application got crashed. And it is rejected by them again and again.
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: I can't debug it, it is uploaded to play console. In my device no error